# How can I check if another application has screen sharing active?

Tags: electron, screensharing

Is there a way to check if screen sharing is active by another application e.g. Microsoft Teams via the Electron JS framework?

I tried to retrieve any information relevant through `desktopCapturer.getSources()`, as mentioned in [this Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39930279/), but with no luck. This method doesn't give information about the state of the source e.g. if sharing is ON or OFF. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any support in the Electron documentation to retrieve this information from the electronJS.